# String concatenation within *ngfor Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I would like to join strings in multiline within *ngfor angular 2 directive.

```
var contacts = [str1, str2, str3];

<div *ngFor="let c of contacts;let last = last; let str = str + c;">
    <div *ngIf="last">
         {{str}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I know the above code is not valid. But I want to know something like above is possible to achieve?

Expected Output should be

Str1

Str2

Str3

Note: I want to achieve something like below code in C# using a angular ngfor.

```
   var str = "";

   foreach(var item in items)
   {
     str = str + item.toString();
   }
   console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something as simple as `join` would suffice:

*untested*

```
var contacts = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3'];

<div [innerHtml]="contacts.join('')"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**update**

`*ngFor` can be used to calculate values depending on previous items.
The best way would be to prepare the list in code and then just bind `*ngFor` to that resulting list.

**original**

You can't use arbitrary expressions with `let`. Only context variables provided by `*ngFor` can be assigned.

This way it should produce the results you want

```
<div *ngFor="let c of contacts;let last = last">
    <div *ngIf="last">
         {{str}}{{c}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just want to display the output when last iteration. output should be multi line concatenated string.

Comment: I'd expect my code to do what you want? Does it not?

Comment: No. {{str}} is not defined here.

Comment: I see. Why would it then be defined in `let str = str + c;`. Can you please elaborate more on the expected behvior? I don't understand yet what you try to accomplish.

Comment: `*ngFor` is not suited for this requirement. Create a list in code that contains these strings and then use `*ngFor` to display the resulting list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127290/discussion-between-chenk-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply output the two strings one after another:

```
let contacts = [str1, str2, str3];

<div *ngFor="let c of contacts;let last = last;">
    <div *ngIf="last">
         {{str}}{{c}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is defined {{str}}?